# Binary trees as innested pairs

Tags: functional-programming, binary-tree, sml

I'm trying to represent a generic binary tree as a pair.

I'll use the SML syntax as example. This is my btree type definition:

```
datatype btree = leaf | branch of btree*btree;
```

So, I'd like to write a function that, given a btree, print the following:

```
bprint leaf = 0
bprint (branch (leaf,leaf)) = (0,0)
bprint (branch (leaf, branch (leaf,leaf))) = (0, (0, 0))
```

and so on.

The problem is that this function always return different types. This is obviously a problem for SML and maybe for other functional languages.

Any idea?

Comment: I'm not sure what your requirements are here. Why does your function need to return tuples? Do you need to use the result as a tuple? Would it be a problem to make it return a string instead?

Comment: @sepp2k No, I have not requirements. I want just to print to stdout a graphical representation of btrees. Using tuples is the only thing that came to my mind. If you have an alternative view, please share it!

Comment: Well, if you want to be able to use the result of the function in other places as well besides printing them to the screen, using strings would work fine. If you don't, you could also just make your function print the tree. That's what its name suggests anyway.

Comment: @sepp2k No, re-using the result of the function is not mandatory.

Answer (score 1):

Since all you want to do is to print the tree structure to the screen, you can just do that and have your function's return type be `unit`. That is instead of trying to return the tuple `(0, (0, 0))` just print the string (0, (0, 0)) to the screen. This way you won't run into any difficulties with types.

Answer (score 1):

If you really do not need a string representation anywhere else, as already mentioned by others, just printing the tree might be the easiest way:

```
open TextIO

datatype btree = leaf | branch of btree * btree

fun print_btree leaf = print "0"
  | print_btree (branch (s, t)) =
    (print "("; print_btree s; print ", "; print_btree t; print ")")
```

In case you also want to be able to obtain a string representing a `btree`, the naive solution would be:

```
fun btree_to_string leaf = "0"
  | btree_to_string (branch (s, t)) =
    "(" ^ btree_to_string s ^ ", " ^ btree_to_string t ^ ")"
```

However, I do not really recommend this variant since for big `btree`s there is a problem due to the many string concatenations.

Something nice to think about is the following variant, which avoids the concatenation problem by a trick (that is for example also used in Haskell's `Show` class), i.e., instead of working on strings, work on functions from char lists to char lists. Then concatenation can be replaced by function composition

```
fun btree_to_string' t =
  let
    fun add s t = s @ t
    fun add_btree leaf = add [#"0"]
      | add_btree (branch (s, t)) =
        add [#"("] o add_btree s o add [#",", #" "] o add_btree t o add [#")"]
  in implode (add_btree t []) end
```